# consumir Web Services vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webservice, soap

estoy tratando de consumir un web services en vb.net
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

llego hasta cierto punto y de ahi no me da para enviar los parametros

```
    Dim Servicio As New Mahalo.GetSaldosModificadosMasivo
    Dim encabezado = Servicio.Authentication
    encabezado.User = "????"
    encabezado.Password = "????"
    Dim Param = Servicio.EncabezadoGetSaldosModificadosMasivo
    Param.fecha_desde = "01/12/2022"
    Param.hora_desde = "01:00:00"
    Param.fecha_hasta = "19/12/2022"
    Param.hora_hasta = "23:59:59"



    Dim dt As New DataTable
```

como podría consumirlo???